# Get all views associated with controller - Zend

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

If I'm going about this the wrong way, please let me know and I'll accept that as a potential answer.

I have a Zend Framework MVC app that is modular, and in one of the modules the site acts very similar to a static HTML site:

```
Category1_Controller
    Category1_Subpage_Action1
    Category1_Subpage_Action2
    Category1_Subpage_Action2
Category2_Controller
    Category2_Subpage_Action1
    Category2_Subpage_Action2
Category3_Controller
    Category3_Subpage_Action1
    Category3_Subpage_Action2
    Category3_Subpage_Action2
```

Etc.. To save time, I'd like to make a function that grabs the current controller, then all of the actions associated with the controller, and create a dynamic navigation based on those two variables (ul/li list to be styled globally). Creating the actual navigation is not a problem, **but how do I get all of the actions based on a controller within a module?** Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the php function [get_class_methods](http://www.php.net/get_class_methods) to retrieve all the methods from a controller, then check each method to see if it ends with 'Action'.

Alternatively you could use [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php), but it's probably overkill here.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually ended up approaching this completely differently. There was no need to have so many actions, so I made a single action for each page type and dynamically routed them from a database to the related action on a single controller. Brain stops working after 12 hours.